# R Control Structure Double Loops

Tags: r, loops, double

Here is a simple piece of code:

```
for (i in c("red", "green"))
    for (j in c("blood", "trees")) {
        k <- paste(i, j, sep=" ")
        print(k)
    }
}
```

I would like it to only output `"red blood"` and `"green trees"`. The remaining combinations are to be discarded. Can this be accomplished within the loop?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a loop for that :

```
R> paste(c("red","green"), c("blood","trees"))

[1] "red blood"   "green trees"
```